# Is my solution correct to CLRS Question 2.1-2?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am currently solving this problem, given in CLRS 4th edition, and I need to know whether my solution is correct.

**Problem statement**

Consider the procedure SUM -ARRAY on the facing page. It computes the sum of the n numbers in array **A[1:n]**. State a loop invariant for this procedure, and use its initialization, maintenance, and termination properties to show that the SUM - ARRAY procedure returns the sum of the numbers in `A[1:n]`.

```
SUM -ARRAY (A,n)
1 sum=0
2 for i = 1 to n
3     sum = sum + A[i]
4 return sum`
```

My solution:

Loop invariant: at each iteration of the loop, the variable `sum` contains the running sum of numbers, from A[0] to A[i-1]

Initialization: before the first loop iteration,when i=1, A[i-1]=A[0] contains no elements,so the sum of no elements is 0.

Maintenance: for each iteration of the loop, the value of A[i] is added to the variable sum, line 3.

Termination: the loop terminates at i=n+1, and according to our invariant we have the sum of all elements from A[0] to A[n]

Comment: There is no A[0]

Comment: I think the invariant I chose is wrong. Is the invariant going to be the array itself? Because prior to the loop, during execution and after execution, the array doesn’t change.

Comment: The number 42 also doesn't change prior to the loop, during execution and after execution, so it is a loop invariant as well. But it's a *useless* invariant. You want an expression that help your reasoning about the program.

Comment: Can you give me some direction, on how to proceed? @n.m.

Comment: Does this invariant work, At the start of iteration i of the loop, the variable sum should contain the sum of the numbers from the subarray A[1:i] ? @n.m.

Comment: Web search the problem, you'll find tons of solutions.